# Retrieve global step number from tf.train.summary_iterator

Tags: tensorflow, iterator, protocol-buffers, tensorboard

I am using `tf.train.summary_iterator` to read data stored in an event file. I would like to access the global step number at which a particular summary was stored, but the [`summary.proto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/summary.proto) has no reference to step number. Tensorboard seems to have access to this information, so I think there might be a way to do this, but I have not been able to track it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tf.train.summary_iterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/summary_iterator) is iterating over `Event` objects:

> An iterator for reading `Event` protocol buffers from an event file.

... which contains the global step number of that event (see [`event.proto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/core/util/event.proto#L13)). Try:

```
for e in tf.train.summary_iterator(path to events file):
  print(e.step)
```